# Consider the set $Y=[-1.1]$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set $Y=[-1,1]$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.

Be $A=\{x| \frac{1}{2}<|x|<1\}$.

I know that $A$ is opened in the usual topology of the straight, because for every point in $A$ just take $\epsilon=\min\{|x|-\frac{1}{2}, 1-|x|\}$, then $B(x,\epsilon)\subset A$.

But how do I know $A$ is opened in $Y$ by the induced topology of the straight?

Comment: $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and $A\subseteq Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Y$ is closed in $ \mathbb R$, we have for a subset $B$ of $Y$:

$B$ is closed in $Y \iff B$ is closed in $\mathbb R.$

Now let $B$ the complement of $A$ in $Y$, hence $B= Y \cap (\mathbb R \setminus A).$

Show that

$$B=\{-1,1\} \cup [-1/2, 1/2].$$

Conclusion: $B$ is closed in $Y$.

Comment: But I wanted to prove that $A$ is open in $Y$.

Comment: Isn't that if and only if it's open?

Comment: $A$ is open in $Y \iff B$ is closed in $Y$.